# How to get a node content programmatically?

Tags: nodes, users

I am writing a module, in which I am required to display contents from multiple nodes. Using the configs I save, I will get the node id's in `hook_block_view`. Using that is there a way to get the contents of the particular node, so that I can manipulate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by 'contents' you mean the HTML for the node in a particular view mode, you're looking for [`node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7):

> Generates an array for rendering the given node.

e.g.

```
$node = node_load(1);
$view = node_view($node, 'full');
$rendered = drupal_render($view);
```